# How to align UIImageView with Aspect Fit to Top?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, image-resizing, aspect-fit

I'm working on some screen in which at top I have an application logo: I want this logo to be resized based on the free size it has. So I configured it with the desired constraints and when it has enough space it like the desired result:

[image]

The problem starts when the `UIImageView` does not have enough space to spread in this case the image is centred in the `UIImageView` and leaves an empty space above it:

[image]

Now I tried to place the `UIImageView` inside a simple `UIView` and place it accordingly inside, but so far without result.

I also tried to search for an answer here but all the solutions I have found:

[how to set image in top avoiding space in UIimageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711133/how-to-set-image-in-top-avoiding-space-in-uiimageview)

[Alignment UIImageView with Aspect Fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272335/alignment-uiimageview-with-aspect-fit)

and a custom view:

https://github.com/reydanro/UIImageViewAligned

were in Objective-C when I'm using Swift. How can I achieve this using the `Storyboard` on Swift?

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout ?

Comment: @technerd No, I'm using layout constraints.

Comment: You can add an `UIIMageView` within a container `UIView`which represents  the available space for the logo, and set a ratio constraint for the image view equal to the same ratio as the image one.

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo, Like I mention in the question I tried to do that, But when the imageview is resized in the UIView it's getting centred in the container.

Comment: fix the UIImageView's aspect ratio: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334017/how-to-set-aspect-ratio-constraint-programmatically-in-ios, and then set the UIImageView's contentMode to aspect fit

Comment: You can use Objective-C classes in your swift project without any hassle: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html.  So you should be able to use the custom UIImageViewAligned.  Then in storyboard, just set the Custom Class of your UIImage to be UIImageViewAligned